# "use Facebook\whatever" seems to not work

Tags: php, facebook

I've tried to go through all the tutorials and answers remotely close to this with no such luck.

I'm able to get my code to work within the same file but I'm trying to work on splitting it out into a class (controller calls on collector).  When moving code to the collector (which I'm including at the beginning of ), the PHP stops at "--->" line:

```
public function FacebookClientObject() {

        $facebookId = "xxxxx";
        $facebookAppSecret = "yyyyy";
        --->FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($facebookId, $facebookAppSecret);
        echo "default set";
    }
```

Assuming this is because the function doesn't have access to the static method, I've tried

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
```

at the beginning of the function.  The collector fails to be included at the beginning of the controller when this is added.  I've moved the autoloader around the two files (including to the beginning of FacebookClientObject()) and confirmed that it's being loaded via echo statements and it doesn't seem to impact this issue.

I've even included the file using

```
require_once(FULLPATH . 'libs/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
```

instead of `use Facebook\FacebookSession;`

I feel like this should be something very simple that I'm just overlooking.

Comment: Any errors in your logs? Try adding `error_reporting(-1);` temporarily to the top-most script to ensure you can see errors on-screen.

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'FacebookSession' not found in <b>.....FacebookCollector.php</b>

FacebookCollector.php contains the function mentioned above.

Comment: I'm assuming the `require_once` succeeds? Try a `print_r(get_declared_classes());` immediately after the require to ensure it has worked - is `FacebookSession` in there?

Comment: I'm assuming this is the main Facebook PHP API. How did you install it - via Composer?

Comment: It is the main FB PHP API.  I didn't install it with Composer, but unzipped to /project/libs/facebook-php-sdk-v4/

When attempting "use Facebook\yyy" I get:
Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in ..../collectors/FacebookCollector.php

get_declared_classes() verifies:
[174] => Facebook\FacebookSession
is present when I use require_once instead of "use".

But I still get the error:
Class 'FacebookSession' not found in .../collectors/FacebookCollector.php

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? I wonder if you are on an old version that doesn't support `use`. Can we see `FacebookCollector.php` with the change edited in? It's hard to help without seeing the code that actually exhibits the problem (if you try something new, and still need help, keep on updating your question please).

Comment: "[I've put the `use` statement] at the beginning of the function" - do you mean at the beginning of the _class_? If you've put that inside a function body, that will be the problem.

Comment: Figured out the issue and it had something to do with namespaces.  Def need to learn more about those as it (in hindsight) was a very simple issue of moving "use Facebook\whatever" to the correct location in the new class file.  Thanks very much for your help halfer!  Can I close this question without a posted answer?

Comment: Just add your own answer, and self-accept (by clicking the 'tick' mark to the left, so it turns green). That will mark things as done here - pleased you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At issue was how I was trying to use the namespaces.

1) I was putting `use Facebook\yyyyyy;` inside the function, and also just inside the class. This caused errors in both places.  Such code belongs at the beginning of the file before class declaration.

2) When attempting to require_once the files instead, it didn't have the namespaces set, so the Facebook autoloader wasn't able to find the classes which also caused an error.  This was even though I could verify the classes were declared with `print_r(get_declared_classes());`.

3) Of crucial importance was adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the beginning of my code.  While I could figure out which lines were causing the issues, I didn't know why before that.

**Thanks halfer!**